# Ajax click event: listing and posting data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I use ajax on my page. I both post and list the data with the button click event.

The problem is that when I post the first data according to the relevant ID value, I cannot see the first data I added (ajax get method does not work for the first data I added).

When I refresh the page, the first data I added comes and then I don't need to refresh the page for the other data I added, I can see it instantly.

Both listing and post are working with the same click event.

```
<script>
        $("#btnAddComment").click(function () {
            let id = @Model.TaskLists.TaskID;
            let addValue = {
                CommentDetail: $("#txtCommentDetail").val(),
                TaskId: @Model.TaskLists.TaskID,
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/TaskList/AddComment/",
                data: addValue,
                success: function (addFn) {
                    $.ajax({
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "get",
                        url: "/TaskList/GetComment/",
                        data: { TaskId: id },
                        success: function (getFn) {
                            let values = jQuery.parseJSON(getFn);
                            console.log(values);
                            let addDiv = "<div class='position-relative'>";
                            $.each(values, (index, value) => {
                                const getCreateDate = (`${value.CommentDate}`);
                                const dateTime = new Date(getCreateDate);
                                const formattedDateTime = `${('0' + dateTime.getDate()).slice(-2)}.${('0' + (dateTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}.${dateTime.getFullYear()} ${('0' + dateTime.getHours()).slice(-2)}:${('0' + dateTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2)}`;
                                addDiv += `<div class="p-4 rounded-2 bg-light mb-3"><div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3"><h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0 fs-4">${value.CommentUser}</h6><span class="fs-2"><span class="p-1 bg-muted rounded-circle d-inline-block"></span> ${formattedDateTime}</span></div><p class="my-3">${value.CommentDetail}</p></div>`;
                            });
                            addDiv += "</div>";
                            $(".position-relative").empty();
                            $("#divCommentDetail").html(addDiv);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```
div id="divCommentDetail" class="position-relative">
                                <div class="p-4 rounded-2 bg-light mb-3">
                                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3">
                                        <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0 fs-4">@item.CommentUser</h6>
                                        <span class="fs-2"><span class="p-1 bg-muted rounded-circle d-inline-block"></span> @Convert.ToDateTime(@item.CommentDate).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="my-3">@item.CommentDetail</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

No error is returned on the console screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divGetComment">
   <div id="divCommentDetail" class="position-relative">
      <div class="p-4 rounded-2 bg-light mb-3">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3">
            <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0 fs-4">@item.CommentUser</h6>
            <span class="fs-2"><span class="p-1 bg-muted rounded-circle d-inline-block"></span>@item.CommentDate</span>
         </div>
          <p class="my-3">@item.CommentDetail</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

```
$("#divGetComment").html(addDiv);
```

The problem was solved when I used the div above.